# Cl has no member vector

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, opencl, gpu, amd-processor

I'm trying to write a Hello World application using the AMD implementation of OpenCL.
http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/heterogeneous-computing/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-app-sdk/introductory-tutorial-to-opencl/

I've setup the directory, lib, etc. [as here](http://kode-stuff.blogspot.hu/2012/11/setting-up-opencl-in-visual-studio_1.html)

The following compiles:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <CL/cl.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    cl_platform_id test;
    cl_uint num;
    cl_uint ok = 1;
    clGetPlatformIDs(ok, &test, &num);

    return 0;
```

}

However,

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <utility>
#include <CL/cl.hpp>


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    cl::vector< cl::Platform > platformList;

    return 0;
}
```

does not.

I get the following errors:

```
Error   1   error C2039: 'vector' : is not a member of 'cl' D:\Documents\Projects\Visual Studio\C++\cl_helloworld\cl_helloworld\cl_helloworld.cpp   12  1   cl_helloworld
Error   2   error C2065: 'vector' : undeclared identifier   D:\Documents\Projects\Visual Studio\C++\cl_helloworld\cl_helloworld\cl_helloworld.cpp   12  1   cl_helloworld
Error   3   error C2275: 'cl::Platform' : illegal use of this type as an expression D:\Documents\Projects\Visual Studio\C++\cl_helloworld\cl_helloworld\cl_helloworld.cpp   12  1   cl_helloworld
Error   4   error C2065: 'platformList' : undeclared identifier D:\Documents\Projects\Visual Studio\C++\cl_helloworld\cl_helloworld\cl_helloworld.cpp   12  1   cl_helloworld
```

IntelliSense underlines `vector< cl::Platform > platformList`, and when i type cl:: I cannot see a vector class.

**EDIT**

If I manually copy the content of the cl.hpp to the main.cpp, I see vector in IntelliSense, but still cannot compile the project.

Comment: Just guessing, cause i don't know OpenCL... but should `cl::vector`  be `cl::Vector` or `std::vector` instead?

Comment: According to the example, I should #define __NO_STD_VECTOR // Use cl::vector instead of STL version, but I still got the errors. std::vector works, but I have to use cl::vector.

Comment: According to the spec, `cl::vector` is deprecated in favor of `std::vector` or your own vector type that quacks like a `std::vector`.  (http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/specs/opencl-cplusplus-1.2.pdf, section 5)

Comment: Ok thank you, I'll use std::vector then.

Comment: @cHao: Nice that AMD uses deprecated code in their OpenCL tutorial (which by the way seems to be about the only OpenCL tutorial there is, too). My application wouldn't even compile when I still had the line `#define __NO_STD_VECTOR` in my code, so that had to go.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `std::vector<cl:XXXX>` instead.
That is what I use, no problem at all atm, and I have very complex OpenCL C++ apps.

You can also enable the internal `cl::vector` class by defining before the `#include <cl.hpp>`  `#define __NO_STD_VECTOR`. But I **don't recomend it**, since the functionality is poorer than std.

***Example:*** 
If you have a vector of events, in std you can remove the events selectively. But in cl::vector you have to do it manually.

Comment: To add something: There is an example code in `$AMD_OpenCL_DIR/include/cl.hpp` and it uses `std::vector` rather than `cl::vector`